# I'm trying to create a user with identity in .NET 8 with Entity Framework and I'm getting the following error, both in MySQL and SQL Server

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-8.0

[image]

`program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default");

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<GerenciadorContext>(opts =>
{
    opts.UseMySql(connectionString,ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
});

builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<GerenciadorContext>();

builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserDao, UserDao>();

builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();
```

As soon as I make a request it returns this error, I don't know if it's something in .NET 8

Comment: did you read error? CONNECTION CLOSED. you probably need to open connection before call query

Comment: Yes, I read it, I'm using the library to make a connection, Pomelo MySQL, and Entity SQL Server, I never needed to open a connection for Entity to work.

Comment: Ok, I'll open the connection before declaring the dbcontext

Comment: Error still persists

Comment: https://dev.to/karenpayneoregon/microsoft-entity-framework-core-8-samples-3dj8

Comment: Thank you power mouse, I solved the error, I needed to make the method asynchronous and wait for it, but I'm interested in the article, I'll read it, thanks for the time spent here, I've been studying .Net for 1 year, I'm in college... I always struggle with errors idiots

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to change the registration from

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserDao, UserDao>();
```

to

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserDao, UserDao>();
```

With this modification, your problem should be resolved.

Comment: Why? Care to elaborate on the reasoning behind this? Why is the problem resolved with this change?